# Composite functions, continuity, and limits

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity, definition

I am looking at a scenario where we take the limit of a composite/nested function

$$\lim _{x \rightarrow c} f(g(x))$$

However apparently there are two jumps being made here that I don't quite understand:

1. We can rephrase the problem as solving for $f( \lim _{x \rightarrow c} g(x))$. I am sure it's correct and fine but I see this statement being thrown around everywhere with no proof or intuition. Why are we allowed to do this?
2. Assume the answer to the limit of $g(x)$ is a constant $d$. Then supposedly $f(d)$ has to be continuous at $x=d$. I think this means $f(d)$ is defined and the two-sided limit $L$ at $x=d$ actually equals $f(d)$ as well. Is this right? Why does it have to be continuous at $d$?
   What about the inner function $g(x)$? Does this mean endpoints of a domain are not continuous (I assume they are not)? What if they are defined? For instance a function with domain $(-4, 4)$ versus one with domain $[-4, 4]$?

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50590/composition-of-limits-it%C2%B4s-not-always-valid-in-the-final-value/50642#50642

Comment: If $f$ is **continuous**, then we are allowed to say
$$\lim_{x \to c} f(g(x)) = f(\lim_{x \to c} g(x))$$

Comment: Is it impossible to evaluate if $f$ is not continuous? Or $g$? I'm not sure where these conditions are coming from or why they are used or why they are valid

Answer (score 2):

It may be the case that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are discontinuous functions, but their composition $f\circ g(x)$ is continuous.

i.e. lets pick two of the craziest (and most famous) discontinuous functions.

Let $g(x)$ be Thome function

$g(x) = \begin{cases} \frac {1}{q} & x \text{ is rational with } x = \frac pq \text{ in lowest terms}\\0& x\text{ is irrational}\end{cases}$

let $f(x)$ be the Dirichlet function

$g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \text{ is rational with }\\1& x\text{ is irrational}\end{cases}$

$f\circ g(x)$ is continous.  But this is pretty unusual.

However if $g(x)$ is continuous at $c$ (as you say above, left hand limit at $c$ equals the right hand limit at $c$ equals $g(c)$) and $f(x)$ is continuous in the neighborhood of $g(c)$ then $f\circ g(x)$ is continuous at $c$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to c} f\circ g(x)$ exists (both left hand and right hand) and equals $f\circ g(c)$

What matters is continuity around $c$ (for $g$) and around $g(c)$ (for $f$).  $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ might do crazy stuff outside of those neighborhoods.

Why are we allowed to do this.

We need to go to the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limits.

$g$ is continuous at $c$

$\lim_\limits{x\to c} g(x) = L$

$\forall \epsilon_1>0, \exists \delta_1>0: |x-c|<\delta_1\implies |g(x) - L|<\epsilon_1\tag{1}$

And $f$ is continuous at $L$

$$\forall \epsilon_2>0, \exists \delta_2>0: |x-L|<\delta_2\implies |f(x) - f(L)|<\epsilon_2$$

Setting $\epsilon_1 < \delta_2$ then $|f\circ g(x) - f\circ g(c)|<\epsilon_2$

We can do this because 1) is true for any $\epsilon.$

Comment: "$f(x)$ is continuous everywhere in the neighborhood of $g(c)$" what does this mean? Does it matter what kind of discontinuities we're talking about? (undefined/removable/jump/infinite?)

Comment: Continuity is defined in neighborhoods of a point.  All the points that are "close" to one another in the domain are close to one another in the image. Close is defined in terms of "open balls" or neighborhoods.  "What kind of discontinuities are we talking about?" Most of the discussion is about functions that are continuous (or at least continuous in those important neighborhoods.)